# How do I get convert whitspace to tab

Tags: vba, ms-word, whitespace

I have a word(2010) dokument with data that looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
15-aug-2017 15:28                Start Template                          Page  2
```

`-----------------------------------------------------------------------------`
`(mm)   ACTUAL   NOMINAL  LO-TOL       HI-TOL    DEVIATION          GRAPHIC             ERROR`

`-------------------------------------------------------------------------------`
`Circle:Ø15_H13_2`

`X-axis(PCS)-74.815    74.940                        -0.125`

`Y-axis(PCS)   74.975    74.940                         0.035`

`Diameter      15.420    15.000    +0.000    +0.270     0.420 -*-+--> 
      0.150`
`TruePos2D      0.260                         1.770(M=0.27)   <--*---`

`----------------------------------------------------------------------`

The things I'm trying to do:

- delete all ---- but not when it's a negative number (-0.125) and replace with nothing.
- delete all +,*,>,< symbols and replace with nothing
- Between all the numbers/words there are white spaces and I want tabs instead exampel: `X-axis(PCS)   74.815            74.940                   -0.125`  between 74.940 and -.125 there are more then 22 spaces so I want 3 tab and between 74.815 and 74.940 It's more then 12 spaces so I want 2 tabs and between (PCS) and 74.815 it is more then 2 spaces so i want only 1 tab
- I want to delete everything from the date to Error
- And the last thing is to make a tab between (PCS) an the - symbol: `X-axis(PCS)-`

so what I want to end up with is this:

`Circle:Ø15_H13_2`

`X-axis(PCS) ^t -74.815  ^t ^t 74.940  ^t         ^t       ^t   -0.125`

`Y-axis(PCS)  ^t 74.975  ^t  ^t  74.940    ^t       ^t    ^t     0.035`

`Diameter  ^t    15.420 ^t 15.000  ^t  0.000  ^t  0.270  ^t   0.420 ^t 0.150`

`TruePos2D   ^t   0.260  ^t        ^t        ^t     1.770(M=0.27)

The error message I get when wildcard = true: Run-time error 5560, the Find what text contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid

and when wildcard = false I dont get a error message but it only delets the text with templet in it and also the text page

So I beleve wildcard=true and that I have a problem with `.Text = "[ ]{22,}"`

Please help me! this is the first time I'm programing

```
    Sub CleanUpPastedText()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Selection.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .Format = False
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
  .MatchSoundsLike = False
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .Text = "[ ]{22,}"
  .Replacement.Text = "^t^t^t"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "[ ]{12,}"
  .Replacement.Text = "^t^t"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "[ ]{2,}"
  .Replacement.Text = "^t"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "[-]{2,}"
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "[ ]{1,}"
  .Replacement.Text = "^t"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "                Start Template"
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "Page  "
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "\(mm\)          ACTUAL   NOMINAL    LO-TOL    HI-TOL DEVIATION GRAPHIC       ERROR"
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "X-axis\(PCS\-)"
  .Replacement.Text = "X-axis\(PCS\)^t- "
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "[\*]"
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "[+]"
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "[<]"
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "[>]"
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

  End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Your requirement isn't clear. Please describe the problem exactly. What you have, what you need, and what you get (including any errors) - with example(s). Try to do it in the Word UI, first.

Comment: Open the document in Word, and then Save As to convert to a plain text file. It will remove all of the formatting and font information. Then go from there.

Comment: I edited my text so hopefully it will be easier to understand.

Ken I will try that

Comment: I solved everything exept the replacement of `.Text = "X-axis\(PCS\-)"
  .Replacement.Text = "X-axis\(PCS\)^t- "`

The problem was that  `.Text = "[ ]{22,}"` has to be `.Text = "[ ]{22;}"
`

Comment: Have you edited your question to reflect the new situation? I get the impression not...

Comment: Now everything is solved, Thanks so much for all help!